# Converting a node type in Drupal 6 after data migration, what are the risks?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, migration

I recently did a data migration from an old site to a new site for a client and afterwards I come to find that the client has changed their minds and decided they now want the blog nodes to become discussion nodes (two distinct content types in the new Drupal 6 system).

What I intend to do now is change the new blog nodes over to the type "discussion". As far as I can tell this is as simple as changing the type parameter in the node and saving it (doing this programmatically of course). These nodes are simply title and body nodes from a D4.7 site.

Are there any risks in doing this since all I care about are the body and title?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got CCK fields attached to the blog type (and you have data in those fields) then you might get some inconsistencies/errors but other than that you should be absolutely fine.

I usually just change the `type` column directly in the `node` table for the nodes in question  to be honest and I've never had any problems.

Comment: That is pretty much what I was trying to do, except I am loading and saving the node with the Drupal API. I saw some other examples on the net of people doing this and they didn't seem to do anything more than this so I am pretty comfortable with it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a 'code-less' approach to convert the nodes to a different type, then I would recommend: http://drupal.org/project/node_convert

Using that module should be risk-free since the node types in question are very basic. I have used the module multiple times now and it works well with both simple and complex node type conversions. It has struggled with node/user reference and filefield in past use cases.

I have never tried changing the 'type' column values in the 'node' table, that sounds interesting and a little scary at the same time...

Comment: Actually I did manage to find this yesterday, but it won't work for what I am doing. The site is at a stage where we won't be adding any more features to it for now. That and it already has an insane number of modules (which we intend to reduce by combining needed functionality and ripping out excess code. Thanks for the answer though. I voted you up.